# How to use group concat to get the 'other' duplicate values?

Tags: sql, sqlite, concatenation, group-concat

Hope the title makes sense!

Given a table MyTable with these values

```
   ID   TheValue
   A         1
   B         2
   C         3
   D         1
   E         1
   F         2
```

I can use

```
SELECT 
    TheValue,
    group_concat(concat) AS TheIDs
FROM (
    SELECT distinct
        TheValue,
        ID AS concat
    FROM MyTable)
GROUP BY TheValue
```

to get

```
TheValue   TheIDs  
   1         A,B,D
   2         B,F
   3         C
```

How can I instead get a result of ID, TheValue and the 'Other' IDs, *not including the ID on that row*?

eg

```
   ID     TheValue   OtherIDs
   A          1        D,E
   B          2        F
   C          3        <null> (or empty string, I don't mind)
   D          1        A,E
   E          1        A,D
   F          2        B
```

(I'm using SQLite in case an answer is dialect specific)

Comment: Based on your example data shouldn't the required result for the first row be `A | 1 | D, E` and not `B, D`?

Comment: Oops, yes you are right. I've edited it for the sake of others viewing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do a self join:

```
SELECT  T.ID,
        T.TheValue,
        GROUP_CONCAT(T2.ID) AS TheIds
FROM    T
        LEFT JOIN T T2
            ON T2.TheValue = T.TheValue
            AND T2.ID != T.ID
GROUP BY T.ID, T.TheValue;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/93a5f/1)**

Answer (score 0):

The first expected output from your question implies somehow that you need to normalize your database scheme, and to say, your Value is an ID and your IDs are values!

```
SELECT 
    TheValue,
    group_concat(ID) AS TheIDs
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY TheValue
```

Should do the job (at least in MySQL, I think in sqlite too).

Comment: The real application concerns a big application used in education. Each row of the table contains a Staff_ID and the ClassCode of a class they teach. However the same class may be taught by several different teachers. For each staff member in the table I need to know who else teaches that class (not including themselves). I'm afraid your solution does not seem give the desired result.